# Yo MEAN Generator Crashes

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, mean

I'm trying to setup a MEAN project but cannot seem to get the generator to work. I installed the `meanjs` generator using the following command:

```
npm -g install generator-meanjs
```

I ran `yo meanjs` and answered the questions about my application, but the generator always crashes.

This is the message I receive:

```
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd mean && npm install
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.7: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
Killed

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:477:12)
```

I have tried all the MEAN version options and nothing has changed.  Below is my folder structure after running the command:

```
bower.json          Dockerfile     LICENSE.md    package.json        README.md
config              gruntfile.js   manifest.yml  Procfile            scripts
CONTRIBUTING.md     gulpfile.js    modules       protractor.conf.js  server.js
docker-compose.yml  karma.conf.js  node_modules  public              test.js
```

I was able to fix the first warning by going in to package.json and renaming the `phantomjs` dependency to `phantomjs-prebuilt`, and rerunning `npm install`. But I cannot find the other dependencies mentioned in the file and don't even know if this solution will fix my problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 14 and have Python 2.7 (somethings I've research hinted that this might be important so just in case).

**EDIT**
One more thing: when installing the meanjs generator I get two deprecation warnings... didn't think this would cause the issue but could this be the culprit?

```
root@area51:~# npm install -g generator-meanjs
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
```

And here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "mean",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "version": "0.4.2",
  "meanjs-version": "0.4.2",
  "private": false,
  "author": "Danny",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.28",
    "npm": ">=1.4.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acl": "~0.4.4",
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "cfenv": "~1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.5.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.8.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "file-stream-rotator": "~0.0.6",
    "forever": "~0.14.2",
    "generate-password": "^1.1.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.13",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.3",
    "mocha": "~1.20.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.2.3",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "multer": "~1.0.5",
    "nodemailer": "^1.4.0",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-paypal-openidconnect": "^0.1.1",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
    "phantomjs": ">=1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "swig": "^1.4.2",
    "validator": "^3.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coveralls": "^2.11.4",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.12.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-eslint": "~17.3.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-mocha-istanbul": "^2.4.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.7",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-protractor-coverage": "~0.2.15",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-csslint": "~0.1.5",
    "gulp-cssmin": "~0.1.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-karma": "~0.0.4",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "karma": "~0.12.37",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.4.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
    "mock-fs": "~3.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "should": "^7.0.1",
    "supertest": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**
Okay so I was able to get the packages installed (I think) by clearing my npm cache, and running `yo meanjs --skip0install`. After that clones the repo, I ran `sudo npm install` and didn't receive the `KILLED` message I mentioned above.  However, all the warnings and deprecation notices remain, and when I attempt the run the server with `grunt`, I get:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:
```

I tried installing grunt manually with `npm install grunt-cli` but I receive the same message.  I noticed that all the grunt tools are reference in `package.json` so I'm wondering if maybe the devDependencies are not getting installed.

And now I'm getting memory leaks....

```
(node:11181) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

How is this so messed up?

Comment: have you tried cloning the repo from github instead?

Comment: The cloning seems to work, it's the node packages that are messing up.  I can get it going with `yo mean-js --skip-install`.

Comment: very strange, I will leave a copy of my package.json for you to check against, as I have no install issues

Comment: What about your node.js version? http://meanjs.org/docs.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is any help, but check against my package.json file, I have no issues on running `npm install`

```
{
  "name": "mean"
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "version": "0.4.2",
  "meanjs-version": "0.4.2",
  "private": false,
  "author": "Amy",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.28",
    "npm": ">=1.4.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acl": "~0.4.4",
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "cfenv": "~1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.5.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.8.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "file-stream-rotator": "~0.0.6",
    "forever": "~0.14.2",
    "generate-password": "^1.1.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.13",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.3",
    "mocha": "~1.20.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.5",
    "mongoose": "~4.2.3",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "multer": "~1.0.5",
    "nodemailer": "^1.4.0",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-paypal-openidconnect": "^0.1.1",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
    "phantomjs": ">=1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "stripe": "^4.9.0",
    "swig": "^1.4.2",
    "validator": "^3.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coveralls": "^2.11.4",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.12.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-eslint": "~17.3.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-mocha-istanbul": "^2.4.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.7",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-protractor-coverage": "~0.2.15",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-csslint": "~0.1.5",
    "gulp-cssmin": "~0.1.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-karma": "~0.0.4",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "karma": "~0.12.37",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.4.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
    "mock-fs": "~3.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "should": "^7.0.1",
    "supertest": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it looks the same for me.  All the version numbers match, the only thing different is I don't have the stripe dependency. But I can't imagine that's why it doesn't work.  I posted my `package.json` just in case I missed something... did you not get a warning about `phantomjs` being renamed to `phantomjs-prebuilt`?

Answer (score 0):

Update npm to latest version before running npm -g install generator-meanjs

```
npm install -g npm
```